# Loop when removing existing ID's

Tags: forloop, loop

I'm using this code to remove duplicate entries from my loop:

```
{% set existingIds = [] %}
 {% for entry in entries %}
    {% if entry.id not in existingIds %}
  <div class="column is-4">
{% include '_blocks/small/entries.twig'  %}
</div>
 {% set existingIds = existingIds|merge([entry.id]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Everything working good but the problem is that if I have set to display 3 entries - I will get 2 or less if existingIds will be found. What I want to do is to replace that duplicate with the other entry to have always 3 entries to display.

Comment: Where do the `entries` come from? Are there more available entries to display in there? Can you simply query more items? How do you end up with duplicates in the first place?

Comment: It looks like this: https://pastecode.io/s/w5q2uqde So in this case I have one article duplicated and that leads that the last block (with 3 articles) display only 2 of them since one was displayed above.

Comment: Why use three separate queries instead of just using one query to get the required number of entries?

Comment: I don't know how to display three different styling in one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example you linked: You can prevent duplicate entries by explicitly excluding the entries you've already seen using the [`id` method](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#id). Since you already have an array of IDs you have already displayed  (`existingIds`), you only need to prepend 'not' to negate the query and exclude those entries:

https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#id

```
{% set featuredArticle = craft.entries
    .section('articles')
    .id(['not']|merge(existingIds))
    .one() %}
```

This will ensure you always get an entry you haven't displayed before. This also allows you to get rid of the `offset()`.

---

Sidenote: I'm using `one()` instead of `all()` to execute the query. This returns only a single entry instead of an array of entries, so you can remove the `limit(1)` call as well. It also allows you to get rid of the loop, since the result is a single entry instead of an array of entries.

Comment: Amazing! I find out how to use slice as well so now featured section looks like this: https://pastecode.io/s/tbmh68a0. I added id method to lower column since I don't want any of featured content to be display in it and it looks like this: https://pastecode.io/s/psqtax01 Is it correct way to implement everything?

Comment: @LukasSnarskis Looks good to me! If this solved your issue, could you mark my answer as accepted? Thanks!